# how to dynamically map a json response object to an entity?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm implementing ng2 where my user.service.ts calls a REST service and returns json like this:

```
getUser(id: number): Promise<User> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:4000/users/1')
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json())
}
```

The returned object looks like this:

```
{
   "Id":"1"
   "FirstName":"John"
   "LastName":"Smith"
}
```

I need to convert this into my ng2 user entity which looks like this:

```
export class User 
{
    Id: number;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
}
```

I'd like to do this in the most generic way that I can leverage as a pattern. For example, something like:

```
var user = userResponse.map(User);
```

I'd like this to use reflection or similar dynamic technique so the mapping happens automatically without any additional explicit codng needed. What would be a good way to do this in ng2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on comments, seems you want to avoid having constructor in your class. Well, the "simplest" solution here is to use `Object.assign()`:

```
getUser(id: number): Promise<User> {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:4000/users/1')
    .map(res => Object.assign(new User(), res.json()))
    .toPromise()
}
```

Now your data is an instance of `User`.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Gzi6tjZzTizDhlMCD1y9?p=preview (check console)

Comment: Great! Glad to here it was a suitable solution! Have a nice day and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your class you can add a constructor which will build the class correctly:

```
export class User 
{
    Id: number;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    constructor(obj: any) {
      this.Id = +obj['Id'];
      this.FirstName = obj['FirstName'];
      this.LastName = obj['LastName'];      
    }
}
```

Check out [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PSvZ7yfuPYQE1dHQM1a1?p=preview) to see it in action.

For setting and resetting dynamically you can create a method:

```
let user = setUser(this.userResponse); // <-- Assuming this.userResponse is the returned object

setUser(res) {
  return {
    Id: +res['Id'],
    FirstName: res['FirstName'],
    LastName: res['LastName']
  };
}
```

Comment: thanks z. I was hoping for something more dynamic. for example, I'd like to to be able to do this without having to explicitly set the class properties in the constructor or elsewhere

Comment: It is possible, but definitely not one of the best structure methods. You'll need to create a method (like the constructor) and then call the method with the var and obj. I can update the answer if you'd like

Comment: thanks z.  will u please post the alternate solution u have in mind?

Comment: I updated the answer. The basic problem is that you have a string for the 'Id' field you need to type to a number. The '+' before the item forces it to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Get the property keys from your json object, then loop through them and assign them to your object's properties by name.

```
.then(json => {
    Object.keys(json).forEach(key => user[key] = json[key]);
});
```

Or as a reusable function like you requested:

```
export class User {
    // properties
    mapResponse(response) {
        Object.keys(response).forEach(key => this[key] = json[key]);
    }
}


getUser(id: number): Promise<User> {
    var user = new User();

    this.http.get('http://localhost:4000/users/1')
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(newUser.mapResponse);

    return user;
}
```

I have never written TypeScript before so I have given it my best guess here. Hopefully it's enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I use Observable instead of Promise, and my code is like

```
getUser(id: number): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:4000/users/1')
             .map(resp=>resp.json());
}
```

If a promise is need

```
getUser(id: number): Promise<User> {
return this.http.get('http://localhost:4000/users/1')
    .map(resp=>resp.json())
    .toPromise()
}
```