# typescript, How do I pass an object to a constructor of class for instantiation

Tags: typescript

I have an array object data get from backend api. like:

```
[
 {name: 'react', age: 4},
 {name: 'angular', age: 4},
 ...
 {name: 'rxjs', age: 2}
]
```

And I definite a `class` and an `interface`, like this:

```
interface IBook {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

class Book{
  book: IBook;

  constructor(book: IBook) {
    this.book = book;
  }

  //I can definite some method here: 

  getFullName() {
    return this.book.firstName + ' ' + this.book.lastName;
  }

  isValid() {
    return book.name.length > 0;
  }

}

//when get the data
const dataModels = datas.map(data => {
  return new Book(data);
});
```

so I can encapsulate some data model methods like `book.getFullName()`

I can use it like this:

`const fullname = book.getFullName()`

rather than this:

`const fullname = book.firstName + ' ' + book.lastName`;

Is there a better way to do this? 
I am not sure my thought is the correct way or not.

The problem is how to convert a `js` object to `ts` class model according to a correct way.

Or, just definite the data `interface`. Is it necessary to convert `javascript` json data to `typescript` `class` model?

-- update --

**especially, the nested data. like this:**

```
const datas = [
 {name: 'react', age: 2, tag: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]}
]
```

Comment: Typescript is converted to  javascript before running into browser. It can handle javascript syntaxes as ultimately javascript is going to run. Your object should only have correct properties by name, and it should be available to typescript object

Comment: @Amit Thanks for anwser, I update my question

Comment: how about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45448199/how-to-dynamically-map-a-json-response-object-to-an-entity/45449684#45449684 gives you more flexibility

Comment: @Kuncevic `Object.assign()` and `spread operator` can do that. but it's not suit for nested data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If no methods are needed, just cast your data. Otherwise, you may copy the data to your class.

```
let datas = [
 {name: 'react', age: 4, extra: { value: 1 }},
 {name: 'angular', age: 4, extra: { value: 2 }},
 {name: 'rxjs', age: 2, extra: { value: 3 }}
]

interface IBook {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface Extra {
    value: number;
}

let books: IBook[] = datas;
console.log(books[0].name); // react

class Book {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    extra: Extra;

    constructor(data: any) {
        for (let key in data) {
            this[key] = data[key];
        }
    }

    getFullName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    isValid() {
        return this.name.length > 0;
    }
}

let books2 = datas.map(book => new Book(book));
console.log(books2[1].getFullName()); // angular
console.dir(books2[0].extra.value); // 1
```

Comment: You mean there is no need to convert json data to a data model class like strong type language `java`? My thought is I can add some method to data model class. e.g: `book.isValid()`, `book.getFullName()`. Put the method to model class rather than use like this: `const fullname = book.firstname + ' ' +  book.lastname`.

Comment: You are right. If you need to add behavior to your data, create a class.

Comment: What about nested data? `for..in`, `object.assign`, `spread operator`, all of them just suit for simple data.

Comment: Use the nested data in the same way. The difference is that you will have to define the nested interfaces.

Comment: thanks. I know it. But I think there is a performence problem. Because if I convert the json array data to model class, I must use `for-loop` to traverse the array. What do you think?

Comment: Performance is, usually, in the opposite direction of maintainability. You should worry if it is essential to you. Also, traversing an array is a very cheap operation. I don't see a problem at first sight.

Comment: It is possible to use a type for the `data` parameter so that we get intellisense about what fields should we pass(without using a separate interface)?

Comment: @Rodris what if the constructor initializer is inside the parent class and I want the child class to have intellisense on it's fields? Do I have to create an interface for each child class even if the class itself knows about it's properties?

Comment: @boyd Intellisense depends on which IDE you are using, it is not about TypeScript itself. Please, ask another question in SO explaining the details.