# Typescript constructor with spread operator

Tags: typescript

Need to assign porperties to the only defined from the interface if used with spread operator.

I am expecting a solution for using typescript constructor with spread operator.

For eg.

```
export interface IBrand {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

export class Brand implements IBrand {
    id: string;
    name: string;       

    constructor(data: IBrand) {
        this.id = data.id;
        this.name = data.name;
    }
}
```

this is one option so the moment when I call this class like this, no way how many members are there but I would be having only `id, name` to final object.

```
new Brand({...data })
```

Case: But when I have 25+ keys to the `data`

```
export interface IBrand {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

export class Brand implements IBrand {
    id: string;
    name: string;       

    constructor(data: Partial<IBrand>) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}
```

I am expecting not to write all properties again constructor. No matter it has 25 it would be just assigning that existing properties would be assigned. If data has `section, genre` or any other property it would be ignored.

My 2nd snippet doesn't work.

Comment: But there are no existing properties before the constructor.

Comment: You need to mention `"id"` and `"name"` as runtime values if you want something to happen at runtime. The easiest way to do this is to mention those keys in an array. (e.g. in TS3.4, `(["id", "name"] as const).forEach(k => this[k] = data[k]);`). The only way to avoid repeating the words `"id"` and `"name"` in the interfaces/classes and at runtime is to create a runtime constant array with those names in them and then derive the interface/class definitions from them (instead of the other way around which won't work) but that is a lot of type juggling just to avoid writing a few string literals.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58788876/2746447

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find a better solution for recurring code using [class-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer) package. It also helps to expose and transform input into the required output.

Answer (score 9):

This doesn't use the spread operator, but you could use the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45474453/251614)

```
constructor(data: IBrand) {
    for (let key in data) {
        this[key] = data[key];
    }
}
```

then instantiate...

```
new Brand(data);
```

Comment: this sounds dangerous

Answer (score -1):

If you are willing to forego inheritance and encapsulation and embrace composition instead, then you can use types instead of classes and interfaces. IMHO this is where TypeScript really shines.

I am going to use a slightly different scenario than your `Brand` example, because I think it demonstrates the power of TypeScript better.

Lets start by defining two types:

```js
type Person = {
    id: string
    name: string
}

type Editable = {
    canEdit: boolean
    save(): Promise<boolean>
}
```

I can compose these into a new type:

```js
type EditablePerson = Editable & Person
```

This allows me to construct a new person like this:

```js
const person: Person = { id: '12345', name: 'Martin' }
```

then use this `person` to construct an `EditablePerson` like this

```js
const editablePerson: EditablePerson = {
    ...person,
    canEdit: true,
    save: () => {
        console.log(this.name)
        return Promise.resolve(true)
    }
}
```

I can also write an `EditablePerson` constructor function that uses the spread operator like this:

```js
const EditablePerson = function(editable: Editable, person: Person): EditablePerson {
    return { ...editable, ...person }
}
```

Which allows me to construct an `EditablePerson` like this:

```js
editablePerson = EditablePerson(
    { canEdit: true, save:() => Promise.resolve(true) }, 
    person)
```

Using the structured typing system in TypeScript brings you much closer to JavaScript and is less like writing in other OOP languages. I really love this style of writing TypeScript because I have long been an opponent of inheritance and always preferred composition.

Using this approach, your Brand example might look something like:

```js
type IBrand {
    id: string
    name: string
}

type Brand = {
    brandField?: string
    brandMethod: () => string
} & IBrand

const Brand = function(brand: IBrand): Brand {
    return { ...brand, brandMethod: () => 'Hello from Brand' }
}

const myBrand: IBrand = Brand({ id: 'abc', name: 'Wonderful Products!' })
```